# What is the correct procedure for upgrading a Grails project from version a.b.c to x.y.z

Tags: grails, upgrade, spring-tool-suite

I have been developing Grails apps for the past five years or so, and I have yet to find a simple consistent procedure for upgrading a project between Grails versions. Typically, I wind up starting the project from scratch, painstakingly copying code from the old project into a new project, bit by bit. Tweaking along the way to get the tests to pass.

There just seems to be too many balls to juggle, from Grails versions, to groovy versions, to STS/GGTS versions. They all seem to be backwardly incompatible.

Comment: following the update instructions, be sure to have the work dir within the project, rm -rf build or target, update all plugins to the newest version, pull up the grails version and then do a `grails package`. and keep the IDE out of the equation.  still things will fail/break.  having good tests helps here.

Answer (score 6):

I actually work with Grails for a few years too and never had to that this way.

What I do is:

1. Install the new version of Grails. I use [GVM](http://gvmtool.net) for that and I highly recommend it, but it depends on your platform of choice.
2. Read release notes for this version and apply them. It's *very important* step. It often includes some Grails "built-in" plugins upgrades and so on.
3. Bump up the version number using [grails set-version](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-version.html).
4. Update IDE settings. I use IntelliJ and it runs smoothly most of the time.
5. Do [grails clean](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/clean.html)/[grails clean-all](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/clean-all.html). Remove `target`.
6. Run all tests.
7. Do some "smoke tests" of the application. Test the most important *happy paths*.

Comment: That's ok for a patch upgrade, e.g. 2.2.2 to 2.2.5, but this misses a lot of important steps in general. You need to update the XML and TLD files under web-app/WEB-INF, especially for non-trivial differences in versions. There are often important changes in the files under `grails-app/conf` that need to be adjusted for. Listen to @wwwclaes - that answer makes a lot of sense to me ;)

Comment: That's also ok for bigger updates, like from 2.3.x to 2.4.x. But you're right - it doesn't cover major upgrades, like from 2.x to 3.x.

What files need to be updated should be described in release notes, right? If it isn't then it's nothing more than documentation issue.

The @wwwclaes hint - you mean to buy the book? I definitely will! But don't you think it'd be beneficial for Grails community to publish this chapter on your blog? ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure no release notes have said anything about making changes to files under WEB-INF, and it's certainly not common; it was assumed for older releases that you would run `grails upgrade` (this was just about the only thing that script was useful for) and for newer releases that you're doing that yourself. Yes, these things should be covered in the release notes, but rarely are

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you might already be doing it right, but if you don't own a copy of "Programming Grails" by Burt Beckwith I suggest you buy it. There's a chapter on "Upgrading Applications and Plugins" that might help you tune your approach.

Answer (score 1):

> You can upgrade grails version with 5 steps

1. Project -> Clean
2. application.properties -> Change app.grails.version = (New version)
3. Your project -> Properties -> Grails -> Change grails installation to new grails version.
4. Your project -> Grails tools -> Refresh Dependencies
5. Run your project

> I think this may be help you

Answer (score -1):

If I use GGTS I do the following:

1. Just in case install latest Groovy compiler (2.3.x) from the STS/GGTS update site (pick Groovy Eclipse). Then select the select.
2. Go to Preferences Groovy -> Grails and add newer version Grails runtime. Browse to it and then once added check-mark it.
3. Right-click on the Grails project you'd like to upgrade. Context menu pops up. Click on Grails Tools -> Grails Command Wizard...
4. Select the "upgrade" command from the list and click Finish. Follow the prompts in the Console view to upgrade the project.
5. Now set the appropriate for the version of Grails Groovy Compiler version via the preferences Groovy -> Compiler and restart Eclipse
6. Fix the compiler version for the Grails project if necessary after the restart.